# How to validate a file uploaded to Dynamics Portal

Tags: dynamics-crm, sharepoint-online, dynamics-crm-portals

I’m using Dynamics Portals with SharePoint Online integration for documents. I need to verify the contents of an uploaded document using C# and display a message to the user before the form is submitted.

I’m not sure on what approach is best?

1. Custom SharePoint feature to raise an event when a document has been added.
2. Plug in code to check for documents when the user updates the form?
3. Call a service through JavaScript when the user clicks uploade?

Any advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You have two requirements,

1. Validate the file content before the file has been uploaded to SharePoint
2. If the file validation fails then display the message to the Portal User

Not sure how you will overwrite the upload button event to call JavaScript to call service. If this possible then you can display a message in real-time.

If you go with plug-in on form update then not sure how you will restrict file from uploading to SharePoint.

Please check if below idea works for you,

Suppose you are uploading documents against Opportunity. Customize your Opportunity form to upload notes/file against that opportunity.
Write a plugin on create of Note along with the file that has been uploaded through portal against opportunity. This plugin will validate the content. If the content is valid then upload that file against that opportunity in SharePoint programmatically else update the note with the message and customize your web page to refresh the page. If there is error show message else show uploaded the file in SharePoint document grid.